# Show icons (or colors) even when the Workspace Switcher is small?

Tags: xfce, workspaces

When enabling "Show miniature view", the program icons are displayed in Xfce’s [Workspace Switcher](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/pager). But when the switcher is too small, it only displays white boxes:

[image: Xfce Workspace Switcher is too small, no icons are shown]

This makes it impossible to differentiate the programs.

Is there a way to show the icons (or an alternative, like different colors) no matter how small the switcher is?